# Avoid trailining spaces on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nvarchar

In SQL Server 2008 I have below table created:

```
CREATE TABLE [Items](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Stock_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL,
    [RFCODE] [nvarchar](24) NOT NULL
)
```

When I insert a new row:

```
insert into Items 
values ('34438913-6CB0-43AD-9DD5-5FBFFC60B313', '70667244-6F03-4113-930E-BF66CF1C29EE', 'MX7A386CHGR5WW', 'BE0000000000000000000162')
```

`Code` column has length 36, which means SQL Server adds trailing spaces to `MX7A386CHGR5WW`.

How can avoid this behaviour? (`code` column can vary from 10 to 36 chars)

Comment: **NO** - SQL Server does **NOT** add any trailing spaces to a column that's defined as `nvarchar`!! It will store exactly as many characters as you pass in - no more! The `char` and `nchar` datatypes will do this padding to the defined length - but **NOT** the `(n)varchar` types!

Comment: From what I understand, SQL will use 2 bytes to store the column length, and then 2 bytes per character (nvarchar) or 1 byte per character (varchar). No padding occurs.

Comment: How do you conclude that it has length 36? By looking at the table definition, or by doing `LEN(Code)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO** - SQL Server does **NOT** add any trailing spaces to a column that's defined as `nvarchar`!

It will store exactly as many characters as you pass in - no more!

The `char` and `nchar` datatypes will do this padding to the defined length - but **NOT** the `(n)varchar` types!

If you run this query after your insert, you'll see that your statement is wrong:

```
SELECT 
    *, LEN(Code), '[' + Code + ']'
FROM Items
```

You'll see `14` for the **length** of the `Code` column, and putting square brackets around the `Code` column **clearly shows** that **no trailing spaces** have been added.

If you add a column of type `NCHAR(36)` to your table

```
ALTER TABLE Items 
ADD CodeFixed NCHAR(36)
```

and then set it's value to `MX7A386CHGR5WW`

```
UPDATE Items
SET CodeFixed = 'MX7A386CHGR5WW'
WHERE ID = '34438913-6CB0-43AD-9DD5-5FBFFC60B313'
```

then when you check, you'll see that the `nchar(36)` is in fact padded with spaces to the defined maximum length:

```
SELECT 
    LEN(Code), '[' + Code + ']',
    '[' + CodeFixed + ']'
FROM Items
```

Comment: IOW there is a bug somewhere in code that is not shown here.

Answer (score 0):

`Code` column is of type `nvarchar`, which means that up to 36 characters are allowed. It will not pad in case input length is less than 36, which is what `nchar` would have done.